# What Software Management tool do you use?

Tags: php, mysql

I couldn't decide if this question fitted here or superuser. I guess it can be moved if not appropriate.

I am developing a new piece of software with somebody else and we are half way now. However, the changes we now make are getting messy as we do not know what changes have been made. So I wanted to know what you guys use to log changes, to log new features that are pending, to assign tasks to users etc. And also something to track issues. For small teams.

I am hoping for a free web based tool that I can install on our servers, hopefully PHP and MySQl based. Basically a small software mangement tool with a changelog, tasks, priotirites, issues, recording bugsm featues etc

Thanks all and apologies if I placed this on the wrong site.

Comment: I think you are asking about "issue tracking" - "software management" is something else.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664/free-project-management-software

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, "issue tracking" tools are good at tracking all of bugs and requests, but there are some tools that are better at planning and tracking which issues to be handled when by whom for iterative development.

Comment: @Neil I disagree. I think it's all one thing. "Issues" and "bugs" are only one type of task/work/ticket which a project needs to track; it also needs to track enhancements, general tasks, testing tasks, etc. And these systems work best when they take a holistic approach to software development management.

Comment: Software management tools are about the _deployment_ of software,  packagesand managing their configuration and  lifecycle once deployed. They are not about issue or bug tracking (which I consider to be the same things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Indefero](http://indefero.net/) for private.

Comment: Just checking this out,its looking really good. Thanks!

Comment: Decided to use this in the end, thanks Luca.

Answer (score 4):

See

- [Free Project management software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664/free-project-management-software)
- [Project tracking/management tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240/project-trackingmanagement-tool)
- [Open Source Project Management Software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366665/open-source-project-management-software)
- [What Project Management software do you recommend for an agile approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572611/what-project-management-software-do-you-recommend-for-an-agile-approach)
- [Which management tools would you recommend for software development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473964/which-management-tools-would-you-recommend-for-software-development)

The top answer lists Redmine:

> I'm trying to get the company where I'm working to start using [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), which looks very good.

Answer (score 2):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is great. Python based, but easy to set up, reliable, and flexible. Integrates with Subversion.

Comment: Damn, just realised its python. Is there a PHP version of this or something similar?

Comment: I don't know. Why does the app need to be PHP? Do you anticipate doing extensive customization? Trac actually is quite customizable without any coding at all; you can create custom fields and customize workflow just in the config. And there's a bunch of good plugins which are plug-and-play.

Comment: I am just more comfortable dealing with PHP and as you correctly said it, incase I need to modify something. Something that wouldn't require a plugin, really small changes.

Answer (score 1):

What about [github.com](http://www.github.com) ?

Comment: I was actually looking at this but I don't want it public and I want something free. I was hoping I could download something similar and install locally, couldn't find anything?

Comment: You can use and install `git` independently from github.

Comment: BitBucket's free account provides 1 private repository of up to 150MB.  http://bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mainly looking for **a version control system**.

There are numerous questions on SO discussing the best solution. For example.

- [A good version control application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960163/a-good-version-control-application) (just an example, there are more discussions on this, just search)
- [Best way to add version control to an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117426/best-way-to-add-version-control-to-existing-project)

I personally use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) for source control.

As a project management tool that integrates version control, bug tracking (tickets), a Wiki, and more, I wholeheartedly recommend [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Comment: Ah, I like trac - just having a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) which offers a license for up to 10 individuals for a measly 10 dollars.  That's a good starting platform to track your bugs, assignment of tasks, and watch project flow.  Better yet, it can connect to SVN (Subversion) which is another good tool you should look into.

Answer (score 0):

- A version control system
- post-it notes (very important to generate, assign and keep track of tasks)
- a very big whiteboard or wall to post the post-it notes

Before implementing Scrum/Kanban for my development teams I've never been able to meet product delivery deadlines. Now we typically complete a project one week early. It's not magic, just common sense organization.

Answer (score 0):

Mantis is PHP MySQL based.

Answer (score 0):

Basecamp is probably the best project management tool you can find. You may also check out [teambox](http://teambox.com/)

if basecamp doesn't suit your needs or seems to be to expensive for your team.